# ng-show based on a value present in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to show a vlaue in angularjs ng-show like

```
ng-show = "role in ['admin', 'user', 'buyer']"
```

need to show a div if role is any of the things in that array.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the function `indexOf` in array to find whether a element is part of the array. It will return the position of the element if found or will return -1.

So you can use an expression like

`ng-show = "['admin', 'user', 'buyer'].indexOf(role)!=-1"` to show/hide data

Answer (score 4):

Or using loDash [_.contains](http://lodash.com/docs#contains).

It needs loDash to be accessible in scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope._ = _;
});

ng-show = "_.contains(['admin', 'user', 'buyer'], role)"
```